# How does $b^2=a^2-ab$ lead to $\frac{b}{a}=\frac{-1+\sqrt 5}{2}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So basically, I came across this particular solution of a problem that starts with

> $$\frac {b}{a-b}=\frac ab \quad\implies\quad b^2=a^2-ab \quad\implies\quad\frac ba=\frac{-1+\sqrt 5}{2}$$

Can someone please explain how the $\frac ba=\frac{-1+\sqrt 5}{2}$ part came about?

The $\frac {b}{a-b}=\frac ab$ part is given as part of the problem.

Comment: Divide throughout by $a^2$, Let $\frac{b}{a} = x$ and solve the quadratic

Comment: Hi and welcome to MSE! Please [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4000170/edit) your question to provide some context and show your own efforts to approach this problem. This is most likely about the [golden ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio), but you don't even mention it. Have a look at [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) to improve the quality of this and futue posts!

Comment: Hey, thanks for the welcome... Actually, I don't even know what the golden ratio is yet, and the equation mentioned above was actually a part of a bigger solution... I wasn't having a problem with any other part, and didn't know how to proceed with this one. But I'll still try to better my posts next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dividing $b^2=a^2-ab$ by $a^2$ yields
$$
\left(\frac b a\right)^2 = 1-\frac b a.
$$
Let $z=\tfrac b a$ to get the quadratic equation $z^2=1-z$ or equivalently
$$
z^2+z-1 = 0.
$$
Solve this using your favorite method of [solving a quadratic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation#Solving_the_quadratic_equation) to obtain
$$
z = \frac { -1 \pm \sqrt{5} } 2.
$$

Answer (score 2):

So we start here:

$$b^2 = a^2 - ab$$

(You can get there just by cross-multiplying in your original equation, the one with the fractions.) Move everything to the left-hand side first:

$$b^2 + ab - a^2 = 0$$

Divide both sides by $a^2$:

$$\frac{b^2}{a^2} + \frac{b}{a}  - 1 = 0$$

To make life easier, define the variable $x=b/a$:

$$x^2 + x - 1 =0$$

This is a quadratic equation in $x$, which is easily solved via the quadratic formula:

$$x = \frac{-(1) \pm \sqrt{(1)^2 - 4(1)(-1)}}{2(1)} = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$$

But since $x = b/a$, then we have the desired

$$\frac b a = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$$

(I'm not sure why what you were given neglects the negative solution of $(-1-\sqrt 5)/2$, as far as I know it's valid.)

Comment: This is most likely about the golden ration, so $a$, $b$ are assumed to be the positive length of a rectangle. However, OP should have provided this context in the question.

Comment: As @Christoph said, it was question regarding geometry and lengths, therefore the negative solution was discarded

Answer (score 1):

$b^{2}=a^{2}-ab$ can be written as $x^{2}+x-1=0$ where $x=\frac b a $. Solve this quadratic. You get $\frac b a =\frac {-1\pm \sqrt 5} 2$.

Answer (score 1):

As you have to find $\dfrac{a}{b}$ let  $a=bt$ and form a quadratic equation in $t$ to get $$ t=\dfrac{1}{t-1}$$